# How to set a tag with the number of observations at the top of a stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I want to set the number of observations at the top of each bar. 
This is some sample data

```
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("", "{\"ImportId\":\"Treatment\"}", 
"Altruism", "Altruism - White", "Piece Rate - 0 cents", "Piece Rate - 3 cents", 
"Piece Rate - 6 cents", "Piece Rate - 9 cents", "Reciprocity", 
"Reciprocity - Black", "Reciprocity - White", "Treatment"), class = "factor"), 
    Gender = structure(c(5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("", "{\"ImportId\":\"QID2\"}", 
    "Female", "Gender you most closely identify with: - Selected Choice", 
    "Male", "Other", "Prefer not to answer"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

My approach was using the following code

```
totals <- Data1 %>%
  group_by(Gender) %>%
  summarize(total = n)

Data1 %>% 
  count(Treatment, Gender) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Treatment, n))+ 
  geom_col(aes(fill = Gender), position = "fill")+
  ggtitle("Gender")+
  ylab("Fraction")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.3, hjust=1))+
  scale_fill_manual("Gender", 
                    values = c("Female" = "pink", "Male" = "light blue",
                               "Other"="coral", "Prefer not to answer"="violet"))+
  geom_text(aes(label=n, group=Gender),size=3, 
            position = position_fill(vjust=0.5),data<-totals)
```

I only want the total number of observations appear at the top of each bar. 
My graph thus far looks like this

[image]

Now I only want to know how to display the total number of observations for each bar.

Comment: I added some sample data

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your sample data to work, here is an example of adding totals to each bar.

You will need to create another dataset that shows totals per each group (for your example, it will be `Treatment`). Then add `geom_text` for your totals.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Sample Data
Data1 <- data.frame(
  Gender = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  Treatment = factor(c("a","b","a","b"), levels=c("a","b")),
  value = c(10, 12, 13, 11)
)

# Totals for each bar
totals <- Data1 %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(value))

# Bar chart
ggplot(data=Data1, aes(x=Treatment, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=Gender)) + 

  # comment this out if you don't want to show labels for each stacked bar
  geom_text(aes(label = value),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+

  # Add totals for each bar   
  geom_text(data = totals, aes(x = Treatment, y = value, label = value))
```

**EDIT (with sample data provided)**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

totals <- Data1 %>% 
  count(Treatment)

Data1 %>% 
  count(Treatment, Gender) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = n)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Gender)) +
  ggtitle("Gender") + ylab("Fraction") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.3, hjust=1)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Gender", 
                    values = c("Female" = "pink", "Male" = "light blue",
                               "Other"="coral", "Prefer not to answer"="violet")) +

  # Add totals for each bar   
  geom_text(data = totals, aes(label = n))
```

[image]

Comment: I already added some data that can be reproduced. Could you please see it?

Comment: Just updated solution for your sample data provided